# Does the key I use for a collection need to satisfy any requirements?

Tags: c#

If I add an object as the key to a collection, does the object have to meet any conditions? I read an article about immutability which stated the keys in a hashtable are immutable, amongst other things, hence this question.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you want to be specific about which type of keyed collection you are referring to... Dictionary<TKey, TElement> perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key for a Dictionary can be mutable but changing it while it is stored in the Dictionary could be a very bad idea. If the key's hash value changes then the dictionary entry might be in the wrong bucket according to the key's new hash value. This means that you won't be able to find it again. From the [documentation of Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> As long as an object is used as a key in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, it must not change in any way that affects its hash value. Every key in a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` must be unique according to the dictionary's equality comparer. A key cannot be **null**, but a value can be, if the value type *TValue* is a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a Key can be any object and cannot be null. For safety reasons the Key should be immutable.

However, you can have:

```
Dictionary<Car, Color>
```

But `Car` should not be mutable to the point you lose or change it's identity (or *Hash* as Mark states).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using classes, and not structs. The considerations are different for structs.

The answer is, "it depends". It depends on whether your objects can logically be called "value types" -- things that represent a logical value of a logical data type -- or not. (This is a bit confusing because .NET docs refer to structs as "value types". I'm using the term in its more general OO definition -- there are classes that are really value types.)

Value types include things like strings, dates, points. In our code, we have a common value type that's just the month-and-year part of a date. Value types are usually immutable. The value's identity is based on its *contents*; two different instances are logically "the same" if they have the same contents. You can have two different string instances, but if they contain the same sequence of characters, they're "the same" value.

On the other end of the spectrum are what, for lack of a better term, I'll call "objects": things that don't represent logical values. These would be things like string builders, and file streams, and arrays, and customers, and orders, and products. These aren't concrete values. The object's identity is based on its *instance*: two different instances are not "the same"; they're different because they're different instances.

So the answer to your question depends on whether your objects represent "value types", under the above definition, or "objects".

If they're "value types", your class needs to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. `Equals` should return true if two instances are the same type and have the same contents. `GetHashCode` should return a hash of the value's contents; if two instances are "the same", they must both return the same hash code.

If they're "objects", the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations that you inherit from System.Object will use reference equality to determine whether two objects are "the same" (and therefore should be treated as the same key in the dictionary), which is what you want. So as long as you don't inherit from something that itself overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, you don't need to do anything special to use an "object" as a key.